# Get most recent date records from mysql

Tags: mysql, database, date

tbl_contacts: -

```
user_id - int
contact_id - int
first_name - varchar
last_name - varchar
date_backup - TIMESTAMP
```

I am having lots of data and i want to get the latest one from the database.

Currently I am having data of 2 different dates, 1 is 2014-02-12 04:47:39 and another is 2014-01-12 04:47:39. I am having total 125 records from which 5 are of 2014-01-12 04:47:39 date and rest are of 2014-02-12 04:47:39. I am using below query to get the latest date data but its returning all the data somehow. I am trying since long and unable to successfully achieve my goal. If anyone has any idea please kindly help me.

**Query**

```
 SELECT `contact_id`, `user_id`, `date_backup`, `first_name`, `last_name`
  FROM tbl_contacts WHERE `date_backup` IN (
    SELECT MAX(`date_backup`)
      FROM tbl_contacts WHERE `user_id`= 1 GROUP BY `contact_id`
  )
  ORDER BY `contact_id`ASC, `date_backup` DESC
```

By using ORDER BY `date_backup` DESC, I am getting the old data at the end of list. But i just don't want the old date record at all if new date record is available.

Comment: try: `ORDER BY date_backup DESC, contact_id ASC` .

Comment: Not working, its still showing old records at the end.

Answer (score 0):

user `MySql` `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` with `ORDER BY` Clause.

```
SELECT `contact_id`, `user_id`, `date_backup`, `first_name`, `last_name`
  FROM tbl_contacts WHERE `date_backup` IN (
    SELECT MAX(`date_backup`)
      FROM tbl_contacts WHERE `user_id`= 1 GROUP BY `contact_id`
  )
  ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date_backup`) DESC, `contact_id`ASC
```

If require change all `date_backup` with `` UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date_backup`) ``

Answer (score 0):

**LIMIT** will do the trick in MySQL database (in other databases it would probably be **TOP** clause). So use **LIMIT 10**:

```
SELECT TOP 1 `contact_id`, `user_id`, `date_backup`, `first_name`, `last_name`
FROM tbl_contacts WHERE `date_backup` IN (
SELECT MAX(`date_backup`)
  FROM tbl_contacts WHERE `user_id`= 1 GROUP BY `contact_id`
)
ORDER BY `contact_id`ASC, `date_backup` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

If you want *ten* of the most recent ones.

The guide for the **LIMIT** clause can be found at [MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

[Similar kind of issue](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?65,7333,112478)

Answer (score -2):

Just add `LIMIT 1` at the end of your query to select only the first line of results.

Comment: I want list of data Nick not single line.

Comment: OK then this has already been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column